# Find duplicates with Datacloud when several request hits at the same time?

Tags: apex, rest-api, datacloud

I have an inbound integration with an external system that I dont control, this system send me details of a contact and a custom object through a REST API.

When it hits my end point, I do some operations before upserting the Contact and Custom object. The first thing that I do is checking if the contact exist, by using the salesforce duplicate rule (I have to allow when duplicate), however part of the logic says that if the custom object status is any of a list of values then the API responds is currently soemthing in the lines of: "there is a process going ...": and nothing gets updated or created:

```
List<Contact> conCheckLST = new List<Contact>();            
myCon = new Contact(
    FirstName = firstname,
    LastName = lastname,
    Email = txtBusinessEmail,
    MobilePhone = txtMobileNumber
);

conCheckLST.add(myCon);
Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult[] results = Datacloud.FindDuplicates.findDuplicates(conCheckLST);
for (Datacloud.FindDuplicatesResult findDupeResult : results) {
    for (Datacloud.DuplicateResult dupeResult : findDupeResult.getDuplicateResults()) {
        for (Datacloud.MatchResult matchResult : dupeResult.getMatchResults()) {
            for (Datacloud.MatchRecord matchRecord : matchResult.getMatchRecords()) {
                if (matchRecord.getMatchConfidence() >= 90) {
                    myCon = (Contact)matchRecord.getRecord();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Depending on what is found in here, the API respond duplicate found or 
.......
upsert myCon;
```

I am having an issue as the external system keep sending several request at the same time, started with 2 and now they are in 3, so 3 contacts gets created.

I am guessing by the time salesforce gets these requests, it havent commited the changes so each time it checks for duplicates they are not in the system yet, so it gets creates 3 times.

I am wondering what can I do to void this duplicates been created?

Comment: Are you required to return a synchronous result ("yes duplicate"/"no duplicate") to the remote service on every call, or can you acknowledge ("message received, will do") and process the inbound records asynchronously?

Comment: Hi David, not entirely sure, I was returning the ID, in case they need it in the future, you suggestion is moving this to @future method? will the future method despite been sent at the same time go into individual queues? for hence excecute in slightly different timings?